# Can't connect to any SMTP server from neither of the Macs in the network

Tags: email, smtp, mac

For a few days now we have been unable to send out any E-mails from various Macs in the network to various SMTP servers. No changes to any hardware or software have been done in the recent time that could block any network related functions. We have already contacted our ISP and they claimed nothing was wrong on their end.

Here's the log entry for one of the SMTP servers we get when doing a Connection Check in Mail (various Versions on different OS' and Macs), maybe it helps.

> WROTE Nov 28 10:23:14.170 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3]  --
>   host:imagine10.server-einstellung.de -- port:25 -- socket:0x12099dfd0
>   -- thread:0x120b33910 EHLO [192.168.2.118]
>
> READ Nov 28 10:23:14.207 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3]  --
>   host:imagine10.server-einstellung.de -- port:25 -- socket:0x12099dfd0
>   -- thread:0x120b33910 250-imagine10.server-einstellung.de 250-PIPELINING 250 8BITMIME
>
> WROTE Nov 28 10:23:14.227 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3]  --
>   host:imagine10.server-einstellung.de -- port:25 -- socket:0x12099dfd0
>   -- thread:0x120b33910 QUIT

Comment: What about the errors on the Macs?

Comment: It's the same error on every system: "E-mail could not be sent using the server XXXXX" And then stuff about double checking login data, which have been double checked countless of times.

Comment: One SMTP server seem's to be working again now, the other is still unreachable. I didn't think it could be a coincidence, but I guess they both had issues at the same time.

Comment: There should be a 5XX error, or something similar,those sort of codes can often be quite helpful. Something to remember next time. :)